# QML object and nest object onCompleted order

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML file which contains an Item, the Item contains a object:

```
QtObject {
    id: something

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("A");
    }
}
```

At the file Item I also have:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("B");
}
```

What I see in the Application Output is

```
B
A
```

What I want is for A to be processed first, is there anyway to do this or do I have to change use a function in the child object and call it from the onCompleted of the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, AFAIK you can't change the "completed" order. But you could control when the QtObject loads. For example:

```
Item {
  property QtObject something: null 
  property Component objectComponent: QtObject {
    objectName: "something"
    Component.onCompleted: console.log("A");
  }

  Component.onCompleted: {
    something = objectComponent.createObject(this);
    console.log("B", something);
  }
}
```

```
qml: A
qml: B QObject(0x351d750, "something")
```

There's also the [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) type, which basically does the `createObject()` for you, though it's meant more for loading visual components on-demand.

Also the "something" `QtObject` could be in an external file, of course.

---

ADDED: Apparently this also works and loads in the desired order, though I'm not sure I'd prefer it myself (but it's more "declarative" I suppose :).

```
Item {
  property QtObject something: objectComponent.createObject(this); 
  property Component objectComponent: QtObject {
    objectName: "something"
    Component.onCompleted: console.log("A");
  }

  Component.onCompleted: console.log("B", something);
}
```

Comment: @SPlatten, I added another alternative... just a bit less verbose. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As you can read from the official documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal), "the order of running the onCompleted handlers is undefined". So you can not trust in your console output for know the object creation order.

If you want load components in a specific order, you can use the [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) item.

Comment: The more I use QML the more I'm trying to make it work like C++, the more I learn about QML the more I wonder where its place is?

Comment: @SPlatten You may be frustrated... I was. It's a lot more like Web programming than C++ or "even" Python and such. Do as much as possible in C++ and leave the front-end as "dumb" as possible. Why not just use HTML/CSS/JS for presentation then you may ask? Indeed.

Comment: I'm frustrated for the same reason. I gave up and now I'm developing as @MaximPaperno suggests.